# Angularfire get list and render it dynamically

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I tried to use Angular dynamically but had some problems in my HMI, so now I'm discovering Angularfire. Doc looks a bit outdated and I found no good example working now. I need to build a dynamic app. I followed steps in angularfire2 docs + stackoveflow to get this:

```
export class RoomsComponent implements OnInit {
    rooms: AngularFireList<Room[]>;

    constructor(private roomService: RoomService, private router: Router, private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
        this.rooms = db.list('rooms');
        console.log( this.rooms );
     }
```

console output: 
[db.list('rooms')](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GvTy.png)

```
<li *ngFor="let room of rooms">
    <pre>{{ room.id }}</pre>

</li>
```

will give error:

> ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]'
>   of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as
>   Arrays.

Tried to add

> | async

But will give

> ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe
>   'AsyncPipe'

Firebase database:
[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Diizw.png)

(If something is added in db for example, it needs to be updated dynamically in each user's page)
Some help would be great !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your room variable to

```
rooms: Observable<any>;
```

To Retrieve data you need to use ValueChanges method.

```
 constructor(private roomService: RoomService, private router: Router, 
 private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
        this.rooms = db.list('rooms').valueChanges();;
        console.log( this.rooms );
     }
```

Comment: I tried that too but have: ERROR in src/app/rooms/rooms.component.ts(27,3): error TS2322: Type 'Observable<{}[]>' is not assignable to type 'AngularFireList<Room[]>'.

Comment: change your rooms to  
    rooms: Observable<any[]>; then use asyn pipe to access data

Comment: Looks working but still getting ERROR in src/app/rooms/rooms.component.ts(31,3): error TS2322: Type 'Observable<{}[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<any>'. Tried to use subscribe to correct that but ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

Comment: Change generic type to any it will fix the issue

Comment: That's what I did: " 'Observable<{}[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<any>' "

Comment: then remove the Obserbale type from rooms and check